# Fabric JS text spacing - character widths

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a project using a Fabric JS canvas that requires text spacing to be implemented - to do so I used the following code ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454373/1135270)).

```
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Text.prototype, {
letterSpace: 0,
_renderChars: function (method, ctx, chars, left, top) {
    if (!this.letterSpace) {
        ctx[method](chars, left, top);
        return;
    }
    var characters = String.prototype.split.call(chars, '');
    if(this.textAlign == 'left'){
        var charShift = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                charShift += this.letterSpace + ctx.measureText(chars.charAt(i - 1)).width;
            }
            ctx[method](chars.charAt(i), left + charShift, top);
        }    
    }else if(this.textAlign == 'right'){

        characters.reverse();
        chars = characters.join('');
        var charShift = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                charShift += this.letterSpace + ctx.measureText(chars.charAt(i - 1)).width;
            }
            ctx[method](chars.charAt(i), left - charShift, top);
        }    
    }else if(this.textAlign == 'center'){

        var totalWidth = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            totalWidth += (ctx.measureText(characters[i]).width + this.letterSpace);
        }
        var currentPosition = left - (totalWidth / 2);


        var charShift = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                charShift += this.letterSpace + ctx.measureText(chars.charAt(i - 1)).width;
            }
            ctx[method](chars.charAt(i), currentPosition + left + charShift, top);
        }    
    }

},
_getLineWidth: function (ctx, lineIndex) {
    var lineLength = this._textLines[lineIndex].length;
    var additionalSpaceSum = 0
    if (lineLength > 0) {
        additionalSpaceSum = this.letterSpace * (lineLength - 1);
    }
    this.__lineWidths[lineIndex] = ctx.measureText(this._textLines[lineIndex]).width + additionalSpaceSum;
    return this.__lineWidths[lineIndex];
},
_renderExtended: function (ctx) {
    this.clipTo && fabric.util.clipContext(this, ctx);
    this.extendedRender = true;
    this._renderTextBackground(ctx);
    this._renderText(ctx);

    this._renderTextDecoration(ctx);
    this.clipTo && ctx.restore();
}});
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be an issue when the text is centered: as you can see in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bslinger/rbow7Lyx/4/) the uppercase I and lowercase L are not given the correct spacing. (It's more pronounced in certain fonts required by my project, but quite obvious here with Arial as well)

I've spent a couple of hours stepping through the code and taking measurements, and the code seems correct, but the output just doesn't match up. I'm pretty stuck, any ideas?

Comment: It may be simpler for  your center aligned text you measure the complete string length to find the start position and then step through rendering each character as left justified. That will save you fiddling around with the alignment. Typesetting is complicated and pixel alignments effect spacing, this becomes more apparent when rendering center aligned, you can not be sure of which pixel column is drawn first. As you only need the string justified, just find the start and render left aligned.

Comment: If you look at the code that I'm using above, that's exactly what it's doing - it divides the total width of the string by 2 and starts from that position, then draws it the same as if it was left justified. It's just that for some reason, when the text is centered, the spacing changes on certain characters.

Comment: Are you sure that the rendering is done with `ctx.textAlign = "left"` as you have not shown the rendering code and I am assuming that `this.textAlign === "center"` reflects the 2Dcontext text align state. To me it looks like you are rendering with text align center

Comment: Ah, nuts. See, this is a symptom of my not understanding the base functionality well enough, I didn't know the 2dContext had its own text align state. I will test this out a bit later and write up an answer if it works, but I'm pretty sure this will solve the issue, thanks.